# Cannot find what is the encoding of the signature obtained by signing with private key

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, python-cryptography, string-decoding, text-decoding

I create a pair of ed25519 keys and then used the cryptography Python library to sign an auth code with the private key:

```
private_key = serialization.load_ssh_private_key(open('ed25519', 'rb').read(), b'123456', default_backend())

with open('ed25519_py', 'wb') as dest_key:
    dest_key.write(private_key.private_bytes(serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                          serialization.PrivateFormat.OpenSSH,
                                          serialization.NoEncryption()
                                         ))

signature = private_key.sign(
    authCodeBytes,
    #padding.PSS(mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()), salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH),
    #hashes.SHA256()
)
```

The signature looks like this: (I've made random edits)

`b'>\xe1\xd0So8\xd1>\xf0\xa4\x18]_\x93A[z\x9c\x04\xf0oo\xc1\xa2\xe6\xdfL\x12z\xa3\x19\xbd\xeeOj\x80\xc2\xacbi\xb6\xd6\x9c*\xaa\xbe\xd4k\x1c\xab\xf8-\xbf\x10\ru\xa9\xe5lV1\x9e\xec\x0b'`

Now I need to pass the signature in the body of an API call, but since it's in bytes, I cannot pass it:

`TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

I am trying to decode the signature into a string but not able to find the encoding used for it.

Here are the docs for this signing procedure:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/

Would really appreciate some help. I'm a beginner to cryptography.

Comment: You're signing using Ed25519, not RSA, therefore the correct docs are https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ed25519/.
It depends on what string format the API expects the signature to be. In case it wants a hex string you can just call `signature.hex()`.

Comment: Also you should never store your private key unencrypted since everyone / every program can then read your private key and all signatures may be compromised; just a warning.